# Java tcp/ip sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Quick question regarding this

```
Socket(String host, int port)
```

If I use these arguments in a client, how would a specify the server have a name and thus reference it in the client?

EDIT

Please excuse me if it's vague.
I'm writing and instant messenger in java and using this constructor for the client side socket, it wants to receive the host's name as a string and the host's port as a int. What I'm asking is how do I set/find the host's name in this case?

For example, is the String simply "127.0.0.1" if I'm running it locally? Or is it a specified name like "JavaServer" that I set somewhere somehow?

Comment: Your question is unclear. please rephrase / elaborate.

Comment: edited, pardon it being vague!

Comment: "how do I set/find the host's name in this case?" if you are able to create the required Socket object, it means you have already provided host and port parameters. so use them. isn't it so trivial?

Comment: you'd need to know the server name (or its IP address) beforehand. You either configure it in a properties file or get it dynamically by invoking a webservice or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could read the documentation for that constructor :-)

It's either a host name (e.g. "chatserver.domain.com") or and IP address as a String (e.g. "192.168.1.10")